# How to pause a loop after 2 runs, insert code in between once, then continue loop where it left off?

Tags: php, sql, loops

I currently have a loop of items being shown on a page.

I would like to run the loop twice (output 2 results/items), and THEN insert a banner ONCE right after the 2nd result, and THEN let loop continue from where it left off.

An illustration below:

{**--- START OF LOOP ---**}

ITEM 1 | ITEM 2
**{ BANNER HERE }**
ITEM 3 | ITEM 4
ITEM 5 | ITEM 6
ITEM 7 | ITEM 8

{**--- END OF LOOP ---**}
<- prev | next ->

The items are inside a while loop:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, img, description, keyword, category FROM images WHERE connect = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $from , $perPage");

while($result = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
LOOP OF ITEMS HERE }
```

I've only ever found "do" / "while" methods, which isn't really what I'm looking for.
If anyone could help, thank you for your time & assistance.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i=1;
while($result = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
    //print item
    if($i==2) { 
        //print banner
    }
    $i++;
}
```

if you want it to print every 2 items the yu can use

```
if($i % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: What didn't exactly worked for you? That as well you need to mention.

Comment: What exactly happened when you tried it? It's hard to guess what may have gone wrong, since it's almost certainly an interaction between the code Neil posted and the code you inserted into it.

Comment: if you've used the script in the same way above it will work. check for syntax errors. post the code you used.

Comment: @Love, care to edit your post instead plugging everything in comment.

Comment: Oh it did work! :)) I'm terribly sorry about that, my bad! :) Thank you so much, that was very quick & very helpful of you! @NeilMartin I deleted my comment since I couldn't edit it anymore. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just print the first item outside the loop, then print the banner, then iterate over the remaining items:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_object($sql)
// print item
// print banner
while($result = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
    // print item
}
```

Neil's solution is more general, but this may be simpler. Note that your `$sql` resource has an internal pointer that doesn't reset automatically, so if you call it once outside the while loop, the while loop will start with the second item. In this case that's what you want.